# Android Canvas.drawText накладываются символы

Tags: android, canvas, text

В моем проекте есть необходимость в создании кастомного view. В этом view, я рисую текст по кругу и при запуске приложения на версиях апи более 21, значения по контуру круга накладываются друг на дрцга

фрагмент кода

```
   private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);
    canvas.drawOval(scaleInnerRect, scaleInnerPaint);

    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(180, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNicks; ++i) {
        float y1 = scaleRect.top - 0.02f;       
        float y2 = y1 - 0.02f; // длина штриха

        if (i >= 0 && i <= nicksShowing) {
            canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);        


            if (i % countWicks == 0) {
                float value = nickToDegree(i);
                if (value >= minDegrees && value <= maxDegrees) {
                    if (maxDegrees > 1000 && i % 2 != 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String valueString = Integer.toString((int) value);
                    canvas.drawTextOnPath(valueString, textPath, 0.0f, 0.1f, scaleText);
                }
            }
        }

        canvas.rotate(degreesPerNick, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заранее благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Долгие поиски и размышления привели к некой логике решения.
Суть такова, что при изменении масштаба размер шрифта  меньше 1.0f не воспринимается canvas.drawTextOnPath(), поэтому необходимо делать манипуляции с увеличением общего масштаба, потом его уменьшения до необходимого

ниже код который работает у меня

```
  private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawOval(scaleInnerRect, scaleInnerPaint);

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(180, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNicks; ++i) {
            float y1 = scaleRect.top - 0.02f;       
            float y2 = y1 - 0.02f; 

            if (i >= 0 && i <= nicksShowing) {
                canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);       

                // вычисляем значение
                if (i % countWicks == 0) {
                    float value = nickToDegree(i);
                    if (value >= minDegrees && value <= maxDegrees) {
                        if (maxDegrees > 1000 && i % 2 != 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        String valueString = Integer.toString((int) value);
                        drawTitle(canvas, valueString);
//                        canvas.drawTextOnPath(valueString, textPath, 0.0f, 0.1f, scaleText);
                    }
                }
            }

            canvas.rotate(degreesPerNick, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawTitle(Canvas canvas, String mValueString) {
        //Save original font size
        float originalTextSize = scaleText.getTextSize();
        float unitPosition = 0.07f;

        // set a magnification factor
        final float magnifier = 50f;

        // Scale the canvas
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(1f / magnifier, 1f / magnifier);

        // create new rect and paths based on the new scale
        RectF unitRect = new RectF();
        unitRect.set((rimRect.left + unitPosition) * magnifier,
                (rimRect.top + unitPosition) * magnifier,
                (rimRect.right - unitPosition) * magnifier,
                (rimRect.bottom - unitPosition) * magnifier);
        Path unitPath = new Path();
        unitPath.addArc(unitRect, 180.0f, 180.0f);

        // increase the font size
        scaleText.setTextSize(originalTextSize * magnifier);

        // do the drawing of the text
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(mValueString, unitPath, 0.0f, 0.0f, scaleText);

        // bring everything back to normal
        canvas.restore();
        scaleText.setTextSize(originalTextSize);
        canvas.drawPath(unitPath, scaleText);
    }
```

Надеюсь это поможет кому нибудь